# Stored procedure time(7) format on insert

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, time

i have the ff stored procedure

```
create  procedure InsertDetails(
 @name varchar(50),
 @lastname varchar(50),
 @starttime time(7),
 @endtime time(7)
 )
 AS
BEGIN
insert into table (
 name,
 lastname,
 starttime,
 endtime
)
values(
@name,
 @lastname ,
 @starttime,
 @endtime
)END
```

when the stored procedure is executed i enter the following parameters, however i am not sure for the starttime and end time as to what is the format to enter the time in. i tried

```
08:00:00 and 08-00-00
```

but i get an error for both Incorrect syntax near ':'.
can you tell me the format its expecting

Comment: whats datatype in database for time storing var?

Answer (score 2):

There's no syntax for specifying `time` literals<sup>1</sup> - you'll need to give a character literal and have the system convert them to time for you.<sup>2</sup>

So, it would be `'08:00:00'`, for example.

Of course, if you're executing this stored procedure from some other language, then you should see if there are appropriate bindings to allow you to pass the data across as a `time` parameter (or local language equivalent) rather than passing it as a string at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>Bizarrely, T-SQL calls these [Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx), but since just about every other language uses the term literals, I choose to use that term instead.

<sup>2</sup>You don't *have* to have the system perform the conversion. You may perform an [explicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) if you want to, but I usually find that this doesn't add anything to the query, except noise.

Comment: I would add a link to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) in msdn, where it notes that the default string format for time is hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]

Answer (score 1):

I got Why you get this error because you did;t mention it into single quote **' '**

you are Doing this exec Like `exec InsertDetails 's','s',08:00:00,08:00:00`

Try to exec Like `exec InsertDetails 's','s','08:00:00','08:00:00'`

[Error Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f92c8/2)

[Working Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f92c8/1)